# Does Linux already implement/support debouncing switch (gpio)?

Tags: linux, switch-statement, embedded, gpio, debouncing

Do we need to care about debouncing when we get signal from one gpio on Linux? Do you ever meet the bounce from GPIO/SW input in Linux? If yes, which is the best implement for debouncing on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the gpio controller will have debounce support, so the gpio controller provides a wrapper function for it gpio_set_debounce(). If your controller supports it should return 0. Also if debounce is not supported by controller, software debounce can be added for example [gpio_keys](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2/source/drivers/input/keyboard/gpio_keys.c)

Comment: Thanks, Prabhakar. With the regular gpio query on Linux from "/sys/class/gpio/gpioxx/value". 
Do you know how is it mapped the file value here and the voltage value from gpio? And Can we check if the mapped value in the file system (gpioxx/value) is already debounced?

Comment: for mapping refer https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt . No there isnt support for checking in sysfs if gpio pin is denounced. If its gpio-keys it should be easy to find in dts/dtsi file / just dump the controller registers.